# Calling a static Swift Method from within Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I've developed a CocoaPods Framework in Swift 3. Now I'd like to provide a Demo App for Swift and Obj-c. Swift Demo App works well, but I'm struggling with the Obj-C Demo App.

After I've done `pod install` and importing the auto generated Header file `({PROJECT_NAME.h})`, I now need to call a static swift method to initialize my framework.

Something like `FrameWork.initialize(param1, param2, param3)` but it seems that Obj-C does not even see my Class..

What do I need to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. I need to import the Swift file with

```
@import "FILE";
```

And remember to tag those classes/methods that should be visible to Obj-C with and `@objc`.